# MySQL Database Performance Deterioration

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm working on a stock project where I am pulling stock data down from an API (ohlc minute candles) and storing it into a MySql server to run analysis on later. My issue is that read and write speeds have rapidly deteriorated as I have stored more and more data into the database (15 to 20 seconds for a write and 7 - 10 seconds for a read).

I wanted to store minute candle stock data that could be easily accessible and simple to query. I know that for the ~30000 stocks that I was looking to pull data for over the last ten years that would give me billions of rows to store. I understood enough about performance and scale that putting all those entries into a single table would not be advisable. So what I did instead was I created an individual table for each stock where it would only hold rows that corresponded to that specific stock. So stock A could have ~500k rows and stock B could have ~500k rows. I used the timestamp of a particular candle as the primary key for each table since it would be unique.

As I started the process of pulling data and storing it in my database it worked really well. I would be able to write thousands of rows at a time with very little issue (under half a second for a write of this size). I could create a table, like say AAPL, that has almost 1 million entries with no problem.

I have done a bit of research on what could be causing my serious drop off in performance:

Network issues: My program that is executing this task has been running over the course of several days and even after making various tweaks the performance remains the same. All other applications in my network are running smoothly so I think network performance is unlikely.

Machine issues: By this I mean not enough cpu/memory/disk. I've been monitoring it over the last several hours and they have the following characteristics:
(This is running on Windows 10 32 bit fyi. I know not the most powerful machine)

CPU: Stays consistently below 10 % but has occasional spikes to ~30%
Memory: Stays constant at ~60%
Disk: stays between 5% and 20%

While this machine is certainly not top of the line hardware, I'm leaning against the idea that machine power is the main issue here (though more powerful hardware would help I'm sure) because the performance has deteriorated but was not awful from the start.

Config Issues: I found a few recommendations of various config fields (in my.ini) to tweak for performance issues. The only one I changed was the key_buffer_size. It was initially set to 8M and I changed it to 32M with no little to no change in performance (yes I restarted the server after config change). I did this because it implied that if the map for the keys was too large it would be stored onto disk thus drastically decreasing performance. I guessed that since my number of tables was now around 10k that maybe that was the issue. I don't know if I should even make this bigger since I'm not sure if that is even the issue.

If anyone knows of a config field that should be changed to support what I am trying to do please let me know. Config is posted here with all the comments that come in the file removed to make it easy to read:

*********** Config Start ***************
[client]

port=3306

[mysql]
no-beep

[mysqld]

port=3306

datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

log-output=FILE

general-log=0

general_log_file="MYPC.log"

slow-query-log=1

slow_query_log_file="MYPC-slow.log"

long_query_time=10

log-error="MYPC.err"

server-id=1

lower_case_table_names=1

secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"

max_connections=151

table_open_cache=2000

tmp_table_size=61M

thread_cache_size=10

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=112M

key_buffer_size=64M

read_buffer_size=64K

read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=8M

innodb_log_file_size=48M

innodb_thread_concurrency=8

innodb_autoextend_increment=64

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

innodb_open_files=300

innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

back_log=80

flush_time=0

join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=4M

max_connect_errors=100

open_files_limit=4161

sort_buffer_size=256K

table_definition_cache=1400

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

sync_master_info=10000

sync_relay_log=10000

sync_relay_log_info=10000

********** Config End **************

Comment: [MySQLtuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) is a tool which can give the tips you seem to be looking for. (There might be other tools/script which do the same thing.)

Comment: are you using myisam engine?

Comment: Jim, Welcome to SO. Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) complete MySQLTuner report 
    - Windows version to download at URL - https://github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: You can't tune your way out of such a performance problem.  For "billions" of rows, we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and samples of all the important SQL statement, including the `INSERT` or `LOAD DATA`.  I have a lot of experience with this type of dataset; I should be able to quickly spot lots of inefficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

(While waiting for the data Wilson asked for, here are some tips.)

`key_buffer_size` is used only by MyISAM; I hope you are not using it.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` needs to be more than a tiny 8M.  What version of MySQL?

Only 32-bit machine?  That means you have no more than 4GB of RAM.  For 4GB of RAM set the buffer_pool to 2G; if that leads to swapping, lower it.

If nothing is showing up in the slowlog, lower `long_query_time=10` to, say, 3.

`table_open_cache=2000` is probably wasting space; lower to 500,